# How to fix error: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Tags: codeigniter

A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning

Message: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable

Filename: models/login_model.php

Line Number: 17

Backtrace:

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\labexercise007\application\models\login_model.php
Line: 17
Function: _error_handler

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\labexercise007\application\controllers\login.php
Line: 31
Function: login

File: C:\xampp\htdocs\labexercise007\application\controllers\login.php
Line: 14
Function: run

```
    <?php
class login_model extends CI_Model
{
  public function __construct()
  {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->database();
  }

  public function login($username, $password)
  {
    $condition_array = array(
      'user_name' => $username,
      'user_pass' => md5($password)
    );
    $rs = $this->db->get_where('users', $condition_array);
    $row_count = count($rs->row_array());

    if ($row_count > 0) {
      return $rs->row_array();
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
  }
}


    <?php
class Login extends CI_Controller
{
  public function index()
  {
    $data['title'] = 'Login';
    $this->load->view('login', $data);
  }
  public function verify()
  {
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtuser', 'Username', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('txtpass', 'Password', 'required|callback_check_user');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() === TRUE) {
      if ($this->session->user_lvl == 1) {
        redirect('admin/home');
      } else {
        redirect('home');
      }
    } else {
      $this->index();
    }
  }

  public function check_user()
  {
    $username = $this->input->post('txtuser');
    $password = $this->input->post('txtpass');

    $this->load->model('login_model');
    $login = $this->login_model->login($username, $password);

    if ($login) {
      $sess_data = array(
        'account_name' => $login['user_accountname'],
        'user_lvl' => $login['user_lvl'],
        'islogged' => TRUE
      );
      $this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
      return true;
    } else {
      $this->form_validation->set_message('check_user', 'Invalid Username/password');
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your result set is empty, the `row_array()` value is `NULL` and you cannot use `count` on it. Check what `row_array()` returns before counting.

---

***Later edit***

Try removing this block:

```
    if ($row_count > 0) {
      return $rs->row_array();
    } else {
      return FALSE;
    }
```

And replacing it with a ternary operator call:

```
    return $rs->row_array() ?: false;
```

This should solve your warning and return the proper result.

Comment: Not realy correct! Before PHP 7.2 the function will result a zero. After that it trows a warnning.

Comment: That's correct. However, I do believe that he needs to check the result set before attempting to count it.

Comment: I agree with you.

Answer (score 0):

PHP v7.2.0  count() will now yield a warning on invalid countable types passed to the array_or_countable parameter.
[see more](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.count.php)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to get the result array? in the documentation in query builder it gives like this.

$row_count = count($rs->getResultArray()) ;

in this case it will always return an array even if you do not have a result in query.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of counting the row array that might be null in your case so you don't have a countable object or array you should count your query results.

```
$row_count = count($rs->row_array());
```

Instead use the count records function built in the query builder.

```
  public function login($username, $password)
  {
    $condition_array = array(
      'user_name' => $username,
      'user_pass' => md5($password)
    );
    $rs = $this->db->from('users')->where($condition_array)->get();
    
    $row_count = $this->db->num_rows();

    if ($row_count > 0) {
      return $rs->row_array();
    } 
    return FALSE;
  }
```

Changed the function to remove the else statement because it was not needed in this case.

Also, I might add that you shouldn't be using MD5 to encrypt your passwords. MD5 is not really secure at this point.

More information on counting database results on codeigniter 3: https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html?highlight=count#limiting-or-counting-results

Comment: If you are using a SQL query string like `SELECT * FROM table WHERE x = 'y'` instead of an Active Record query, then instead you will have to use `num_rows()` as in `->num_rows()`

Answer (score 0):

In Model:

```
function getPaymentTotalCount($search)
{
    $sql = 'SELECT id FROM tbl_payment WHERE '.$search;
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->num_rows();  // <- replace row() to num_rows()
}
```